# facebook pixel timer code

Tags: javascript, facebook-pixel

I need to put this timer  in my facebook pixel code

```
setTimeout(function(){ insert Facebook pixel code here}, 3000);
```

can anyone tell me exactly where I should place it in the code or do I simply place the entire facebook pixel code within the curly brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I use facebook pixel at work & I refer to https://en-gb.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755

Your requirement is to track event once every 3 secs. For this to work, put the timer event code in your JS code and make sure its executed.

- Pixel script tag goes into head section
- Your site JS goes towards end of the body
- Timer event is inside your JS file.

I am not sure about your JS file architecture. Just make sure it gets executed. You can also put in window.load.

Comment: Thanks, still a bit confused, the instructions from the website are;

Comment: Use the following piece of code and put it within the Facebook Pixel snippet: setTimeout(function(){ insert Facebook pixel code here}, 3000); This basically tells the Pixel to fire ONLY when your visitor stayed on your website for 3 seconds (or 3,000 milliseconds). Doing this you ensure that people who leave immediately (or maybe even bots) are not counted as Pixel fires that might mess up your data.

Comment: so I assume the facebook pixel number is what I insert into the curly brackets?

Comment: @WaynePatt No, you would put the whole Pixel code there.